# Python 2.7 - Trying to find the min and max of numbers input by the user

Tags: python, input, max, min

The code below is printing the values of max_num and min_num as "None". I am an absolute beginner so any info is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
while True:
    number = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
    num_list = list()
    max_num = None
    min_num = None
    if number == "done":
        print "The maximum number is:", max_num
        print "The minimum number is:", min_num
        break
    try:
        number = int(number)
        num_list.append(number)
        for num in num_list:
            if max_num is None or num > max_num:
                max_num = num
            if min_num is None or num < min_num:
                min_num = num
    except:
        print "You did not enter a number"
```

Comment: You're setting `max_num` and `min_num` to `None` before you print them every time you loop. You're also redeclaring `num_list`.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would ASK your question, not just state your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You set `num_list`, `max_num` and `min_num` to `None` at the beginning of your loop.

```
while True:
    number = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
    num_list = list() #these
    max_num = None #three
    min_num = None #lines
```

This means that every iteration (i.e. after you enter each number) they get reset to `None`.

Move these outside the loop.

---

Note: since you don't actually use the list elements elsewhere, you might as well not keep track. (`try` block omitted in following code snippet)

```
max = None
min = None
while True:
    number = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    if max is None or number > max:
        max = number
    if min is None or number < min:
        min = number
```

Comment: Aaargh its so obvious when its pointed out. Thanks for your help, its working as it should now

Comment: For the record (I already wrote a code snippet anyway, but just to make sure its applicable), do you need the list elements/previously entered numbers elsewhere?

Comment: No it just needs to print out the the maximum and minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistakes are:

- inistialization of `max_num` and `min_num` inside the loop
- saving numbers in a list is not necessary to calculate max and min.
- you can replace the `try` instruction by using `isdigit` test.

Fixes for your code:

```
max_num = 0
min_num = 9999999999
while True:
    number = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")

    if number == "done":
        break
    if number.isdigit():
        number = int(number)
        if min_num> number:
             min_num = number
        if max_num < number:
             max_num = number
    else:
        print "You did not enter a number"

print "The maximum number is:", max_num
print "The minimum number is:", min_num
```

--

An alternative solution using a list:

```
num_list = []
while True:
    number = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
    if number == "done":
            break
    if number.isdigit():
        num_list.append(int(number))
    else:
        print "You did not enter a number"

print "The maximum number is:", max(num_list)
print "The minimum number is:", min(num_list)
```